# MercadoPago API Java ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven, classnotfoundexception

The tutorial says that I just have to put these on maven:

```
<repository>
    <id>mercadopago</id>
    <url>https://github.com/mercadopago/sdk-java/raw/master/releases</url>
</repository>



<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mercadopago</groupId>
    <artifactId>sdk</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

API (https://www.mercadopago.com.br/developers/en/tools/sdk/server/java#install)
and I did, but I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mercadopago/MP
    at io.github.margato.vippago.Main.onEnable(Main.java:31)
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:217)
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:457)
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:382)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_5_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:305)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_5_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:287)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_5_R3.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:630)
    at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:275)
    at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:24)
    at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:189)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_5_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:546)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_5_R3.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:535)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R3.DedicatedServer.an(DedicatedServer.java:263)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R3.DedicatedServer.r(DedicatedServer.java:228)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R3.MinecraftServer.q(MinecraftServer.java:472)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:404)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R3.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:573)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mercadopago.MP
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass0(PluginClassLoader.java:80)
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:53)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 17 more
```

What do I have to do?

Comment: Did you check, that required dependency is downloaded ?

Comment: Where do I see the dependencies?

Comment: Which IDE your using ?

Comment: I'm using eclipse

Comment: Normally you will have external library section under your project structure. see the image in the answer of this question, although its for intellij but same external library section is present under eclipse as well.

Comment: Using command line also you can check it, please follow http://www.mkyong.com/maven/where-is-maven-local-repository/ on how to do it

Comment: http://imgur.com/AcxHTkf

Comment: image is not complete, please search your sdk, jar is listed under maven dependency or not ?

Comment: the sdk you're saying isn't the first one listed?

Comment: ohh yeah, my mistake , how are you build the project , i mean which version of java and which mvn command you are using?

Comment: My project requires java 7, I'm using Maven Build -> clean install

Comment: During  `mvn clean install` are you getting this error?

Comment: I just setup it in my local env. , and its working fine for me

Comment: I'm not getting any erros during `mvn clean install`